# using uiautomation dll in node ffi

Tags: javascript, electron, ui-automation, ffi

How to use windows uiautomation in node-ffi-napi? For example, I want to use the ElementFromPoint function. Here are two documents:

- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.automation.automationelement.frompoint?view=windowsdesktop-8.0
- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/uiautomationclient/nn-uiautomationclient-iuiautomation

I don't know which should I refer, and I don't know how to import the function using ffi. Should I consider about COM? Here is my code:

```
const pathToDll ='./lib/win/UIAutomationCore';

const POINT = Struct({
  'x': 'long',
  'y': 'long'
});

const IUIAutomationElementPtr = ref.refType('void');

const uiautomation = ffi.Library(pathToDll, {
  'ElementFromPoint': ['long', [POINT, 'pointer']]
});

const point = new POINT();
point.x = 100; 
point.y = 100;

const elementPtr = ref.alloc(IUIAutomationElementPtr);

const hr = uiautomation.ElementFromPoint(point, elementPtr);

if (hr === 0) { // S_OK
  const element = ref.deref(elementPtr);
  console.log(element)
...
} else {
...
}
```

But it returns `Error: Dynamic Symbol Retrieval Error: Win32 error 127`

pls help me thanks!!